# Why is this simple piece of C code giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcpy

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int size_to_alloc = sizeof(char*) * 1;
    char** p = (char**) malloc(size_to_alloc);
    p[0] = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 10);
    strcpy("hello", p[0]);
    printf("%s\n", p[0]);
}
```

I am obviously missing something very basic but can't figure out what.

Comment: strcpy has the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Marking the first answer by Dilip as accepted.

Comment: Dilip's answer is actually the last one ;-). All other answers were posted 15 minutes before, in the space of 1 minute.  keithmo's comment was even faster, providing the correct answer in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: oh is it! changing accepted to yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strcpy` takes its arguments in the opposite order: destination first, source second. Try:

```
strcpy(p[0], "hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

`strcpy()` function has argument mismatch.

usage of string copy as per the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`

So your `strcpy()` call has to be `strcpy(p[0], "hello");`

Answer (score 0):

Just make small change in **[strcpy](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm)** function : **`char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src)`**.

**dest** : the destination array
**src** :  string to be copied.

Like:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int size_to_alloc = sizeof(char*) * 1;
    char** p = (char**) malloc(size_to_alloc);
    p[0] = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 10);
    strcpy(p[0],"Hello");      /* change */
    printf("%s\n", p[0]);
}
```

> **Output:**  Hello

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) of `strcpy()`. It says

> `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`

So, you need to have the **first** argument as the **destination** (aka, *copy to*), **second** one as **source** (aka *copy from*).

In your case, `"hello"` has been supplied as the *copy to* address and `"hello"` being a string literal, attempt to copy anything into it (i.e.,modification of a string literal) will result in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which leads to the segmentation fault.

Solution: swap the arguments of the function call.